# CDMA Signal strength in dbm

Tags: android, signals, signal-strength, cdma

iam developing an android app where i want to get the range of signal values for GSM and CDMA coverage. I am displaying the dbm values for GSM coverage using the below code

```
  gsmStrength = String.valueOf(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() * 2 - 113);
  String phnstrngth = MyListener.getStrength() + "dBm";
```

The above code gives me the dbm values for GSM Coverage. Similarly i want to get the dbm values for CDMA Coverage. Not Getting how to do it! Please Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's actually simpler for CDMA because the API provides the signal strength in dBm:

```
  cdmaStrength = String.valueOf(signalStrength.getCdmaDbm();
  String phnstrngth = MyListener.getStrength() + "dBm";
```